# Progress bar not working properly in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, download, progress-bar, mp4

I have created a program that downloads mp4 videos from a link. I've added the code below

```
chunk_size = 256
URL = 'https://gogodownload.net/download.php?url=aHR0cHM6LyAdrefsdsdfwerFrefdsfrersfdsrfer363435349URASDGHUSRFSJGYfdsffsderFStewthsfSFtrftesdfseWVpYnU0bmM3LmdvY2RuYW5pLmNvbS91c2VyMTM0Mi9lYzBiNzk3NmM1M2Q4YmY5MDU2YTYwNjdmMGY3ZTA3Ny9FUC4xLnYwLjM2MHAubXA0P3Rva2VuPW8wVnNiR3J6ZXNWaVA0UkljRXBvc2cmZXhwaXJlcz0xNjcxOTkzNzg4JmlkPTE5MzU1Nw=='
x = requests.head(URL)
y = requests.head(x.headers['Location'])

file_size = int(y.headers['content-length'])

response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        f.write(chunk)
```

This code works properly and downloads the video but I want to add a live progress bar. I Tried using `alive-progress` (code added below) but it didnt work properly.

```
def compute():
    response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
    with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            f.write(chunk)
            yield 256

with alive_bar(file_size) as bar:
    for i in compute():
        bar()
```

This is the response I got, however the file downloaded properly
[image: Alive Progress]

Any help?

Comment: What is `alive_bar()`?

Comment: its a library that creates a fancy progress bar, I saw it in another answer on stack

Comment: @MythicalPhantom You're updating the bar with `bar()` when you've wrote the chunk (I suppose it's 256 bytes). So the total calls to `bar()` is 256 times smaller that total file_size. Try to initialize the bar with `with alive_bar(file_size // 256) as bar:` or call the bar with `bar(256)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you should try. I updated your chunk_size property to match the file size, which I also converted into KB (Kilo Bytes). It shows the values properly alongside the percentage as well

As for the weird boxes showing up on your terminal, that is because your terminal does not support the encoding used by the library. Maybe try editing your terminal settings to support "UTF-8" or higher

```
file_size = int(int(y.headers['content-length']) / 1024)
chunk_size = 1024

def compute():
    response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
    with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            f.write(chunk)
            yield 1024

with alive_bar(file_size) as bar:
    for i in compute():
        bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is happening because your terminal does not support the encoding which is being printed. Edit the settings of your terminal app to support UTF-8 encoding or higher (preferably, UTF-16 or UTF-32).

Also give tqdm a try. It is a more reknowned library so you know it has been tried and tested.